# DPKG error while installation bcmwl-kernel-source on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, apt, dpkg, broadcom

I was purging bcmwl-kernel-source, but during the process Iinterrupted it by mistake. Now when I am trying to install it again using `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source` I get the following error

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 393 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.2) ...
Removing old bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
Error! DKMS tree already contains: bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
dpkg: error processing package bcmwl-kernel-source (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bcmwl-kernel-source
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: have you tried the usual `sudo apt-get -f install`  (-f is shorthand for --fix-broken); then maybe the `sudo dpkg-reconfigure bcmwl-kernel-source`

Comment: Ya.. tried all that

Comment: Answer by @Atef works for 20.04. (Someone please update OP title to indicate that)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If anyone is still facing this issue using Ubuntu 20.04, try the following:

```
apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
apt-get install broadcom-sta-source
apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms
apt-get install broadcom-sta-common
```

Thanks to **Rafael Santos (rafae-s)**  from the link below

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1878045

Comment: This worked, thank you so much!

Comment: I was facing the same issue

Comment: Thanks a lot man

Comment: Thank you for shared and thank you so much to Rafael Santos (rafae-s)

Comment: (not from me but totally appropriate): Man, you deserve a huge cookie.

Comment: It even solves the issue of connecting to 5G Wifi as well.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me
`rm -rf /usr/src/bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom` and then `rm -rf /var/lib/dkms/*` followed by `apt-get purge dkms`. After that I just did `apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source` and it installed.

Comment: You need `dkms` to automatically recompile `bcwl` source code with every kernel update. Now you will have to manually compile it for all new kernels.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix how do i fix it now so that `dkms` automatically recompiles `bmwl` source code?

Answer (score -2):

For anyone facing this issue on 20.04

This issue is caused when attempting to manually install "bcmwl-kernel-source" or using "Additional Drivers".

Just run this command
`sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source`

Comment: So why remove them if they are needed? Maybe your device is different.